# HTTP-Based Public Key Pinning is deprecated warning when using Yahoo Weather API

Tags: yql, yahoo-weather-api

I'm trying to implement the basic Yahoo weather API JS example from https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/#js

In chrome version 70, I'm getting the following warning:

`HTTP-Based Public Key Pinning is deprecated. Chrome 69 and later will ignore HPKP response headers. (Host: query.yahooapis.com)`

Is there another way I need to consume the API to avoid this warning? I've also tried like this but I got the same warning

`fetch("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select wind from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text='chicago, il')&format=json")
          .then(response => {
            response.json().then(data => {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
            })
          })`